# How to make several parameters in a template for a call without overloads?

Tags: c++, c++20

How to make one template so that it can be called with several parameters, without creating unnecessary overloads with code repetition

I have a template something like this

```
struct demo {
  template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
  demo(T1&& tipe_1, T2&& tipe_2, T3&& tipe_3) {
   // code that is too lazy to repeat
   std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1 / tipe_2);  
  }
  // I could do this, but I don't want to repeat a lot of code from the template, I showed this as an 
  // example of what I want to achieve  
  
  template <class T1,class T3>
  demo(T1&& tipe_1, T3&& tipe_3) {
   // code that is too lazy to repeat
   std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1);
  }
}

int main () {
 demo(tipe_1,tipe_2,tipe_3);
 demo(tipe_1,tipe_3);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO: This depends way too much on the use case for an appropriate answer.
There is a multitude of solutions: Variadic templates, chained CTORs, private/static function with the duplicated code, ...

Comment: @SimonKraemer It's perfectly acceptable for there to be multiple solutions. Each answer could show a different approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use C++17 [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) for this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void createFullPath(Ts&&... components)
{
  std::filesystem::create_directories((std::filesystem::path{components} / ...));
}
```

[Live demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/EhGa7q).

Note this requires all `Ts` to have a proper `operator/` functionality, which would make them `std::filesystem::path` or equivalent

In general, it really depends on what you want to do with the arguments how to write the generic template.

Comment: I don't really understand how this patch will work, do you need to write it inside the template?
like so or what? `createFullPath(tipe_1, tipe_2);`

Comment: The second example will not work this way. This would add non-template-type parameters of type std::filesystem::path (which I do not think is possible). This would not add the possibility to have multiple arguments of this type but rather introduce components as compile time arguments.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use this code yet, but I'm trying to come up with something

Comment: The rhs of `std::filesystem::path::operator/` need not be `std::filesystem::path`, it can be a string

Comment: the compiler does not understand something in this line `std::filesysteam::create_directories(components / ...);`

Comment: writes syntax error unexpected token "..."; expression required

Comment: now writes it is impossible to convert the "initializer list" to demo
the error happens where I try to call this template

Comment: It would be helpful to provide e.g. a godbolt link with the exact code you're trying to compile, or formulate a new question with that information if you think the current question has been answered.

Comment: this question is answered, but I need to understand how to pass several parameters through a template to another template
`1)`  ` createFullPath("bla");`
 `2)`  createFullPath("bla", "bloe");

Comment: as well as if there is a number and not a text
`3)` createFullPath("bla", 2);

Comment: With the code in this answer, a `std::filesystem::path` needs to be constructible from each parameter. This is a good thing. A number (an `int`) is not a path component, nor should it be. If you want it to be, the caller should convert it in the way he wants to convert it.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a number, it doesn't work, I used to do this, but now the template is different
`if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T1, int &> {
fix = std::to_string(componnents);
} else {
fix = componnents;
}` well, in short, I can't add to this template, this piece of code

Comment: Please ask a new question about this problem specifically

Comment: I cannot ask questions yet, there is a limitation here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919803/how-to-make-a-template-without-overloads-and-use-different-calls